# Enabling "Toast Notifications" for Windows 8 Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'd like to enable Toast Notifications for a Windows 8 Store Application i am building.

The documentation says:
"Simply set the Toast Capable option to "Yes" in the Notifications section of the Application UI tab."

(Taken from [How to opt in for toast notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh781238))

Unfortunately, the Visual Studio manifest editor doesn't seem to have this option.

Am i missing anything?

*I know this can be done by editing the manifest file, but i am just wondering why it is missing from Visual Studio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is accessible from the Visual Studio manifest editor.  Make sure that you are on the "Application UI" tab.  Then at the bottom, select "All Image Assets" in the left-hand sidebar, and under a "Notifications" section, the first option is "Toast capable".

Comment: I am now on Visual Studio 2015 and for a Universal App (Windows 10) that "Toast capable" combo in a Notifications section seems to be available no more, at least from the graphical UI ... I don't know if it can be inserted in the xml ... Any suggestion how to set now a Win 10 Universal App to be Toast capable?