# WNS - Tiles are delivered and Toasts not

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, toast, wns

I have a big problem with the deliveration of Toast-Messages. The tiles are delivered as expeceted.
The **first toast message** I send to the device (with a new push URL) gets a resonse header with

```
X-WNS-NOTIFICATIONSTATUS: received
X-WNS-STATUS: received
```

but the toast is **not delivered** to the device.

If I send the toast **another time** the response from Microsoft looks like

```
X-WNS-NOTIFICATIONSTATUS: dropped
X-WNS-STATUS: dropped
X-WNS-ERROR-DESCRIPTION: Blocked channel URL
```

My **HTTP-Requsest** looks like this:

URL:

```
https://db5.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAAC5SQWdpe....25osxgpm3dB3zTN8io2OPMUIRs%3d
```

Header:

```
Content-Length: 102
X-WNS-Type: wns/toast
Authorization: Bearer EgAZAQMAA...
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Body:

```
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastText01">
            <text id="1">bodyText</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

I hope someone can help me with this!

kind regards,

Bruno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you've set the Toast Capable option in your appx manifest to true first.

Check step 1 of this documentation: [Enabling "Toast Notifications" for Windows 8 Store App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366782/enabling-toast-notifications-for-windows-8-store-app) or Visual Studio instructions here: [Enabling "Toast Notifications" for Windows 8 Store App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366782/enabling-toast-notifications-for-windows-8-store-app)

Comment: Thanks, after I enabled the push ability it worked just fine!